# How can I make a time-limited trial application?

Tags: android, android-lvl, copy-protection

I'd like be able to make a time-limited trial version of my application, but I'm not sure how I can reliably determine whether or not the user attempted to reinstall the application after the expiration date.

I could likely store the initial installation date in a storage location that wouldn't get erased upon uninstall, but this doesn't seem like an ideal method.  Does Google Play's [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/licensing/index.html) support this feature, or is there another acceptable way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you send a uuid back to your server upon installation?

Comment: @OrionRogue That seems like a good idea; then the server could maintain the original installation date.  I assume that's what you had in mind?

Comment: it is, although you'd need to consider some real world possibilities, like someone tried to install your app and had no success, so uninstalled it and tried again later.  Depending on your appplication, limiting the ability to import/export data on your trial version may mitigate the usefulness of uninstall/reinstall users.  Good luck.

Comment: @OrionRogue if you move (and delete) your comments to an answer, I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo what was written in the comments:

Have the device create a UUID, then send the UUID to a server like was mentioned. Every time the app is used or every couple days, which ever is more, check if the app trial has expired and should be disabled IN the Licensing Services policy. That way you can have the licensing service disable the application for you.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I misread what the document said. I'll update the answer with better information.